# Hölder continuity of brownian motions moments

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

We know the paths of Brownian motion are a.s. hölder continous with $\alpha \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ that
is a.s. $$|W(t)-W(s)|\leq C(\omega)|t-s|^{\alpha} $$ for $t,s\geq0$. This result is tight.
What about a similiar result in $L^p$ norms ($p\geq 1$)?
$$\mathbb{E}[|W(t)-W(s)|^p]^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq C|t-s|^{\alpha}$$
In my textbook this case is not covered altough this seems to me like a nice addition to hölder continuity of Brownian motion if it is true.

In mathoverflow it is claimed to be true for $\alpha \in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ but I have some trouble understanding the proof. Also we still don't know whether it's tight.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304238/moments-of-the-h%C3%B6lder-norm-of-brownian-process

I'm especially interested in case $p=2$ and I'd appreciate some tips for literature about this.

Comment: This is immediate since $W(t)-W(s)$ is Gaussian with variance $|t-s|$, and a Gaussian variable has finite moments of all orders.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Thank you! So $$\mathbb{E}[|W(t)-W(s)|^2]=|t-s|$$ and therefore $$\mathbb{E}[|W(t)-W(s)|^2]^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq |t-s|^{\alpha}$$ for $\alpha \in (0,\frac{1}{2}]$

Comment: That is fine for $p=2$ and $p \le 2$. For $p>2$ you need to use the Gaussian distribution.